# Tailwind `@apply` utility not working in storybook

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, tailwind-css, storybook

`@apply` utility is being compiled to normal CSS and is flagged as invalid syntax in storybook

Here's my `main.js`

```
// .storybook/main.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  staticDirs: ["../public"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-scss",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-postcss",
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require("postcss"),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    const rules = config.module.rules;
    const fileLoaderRule = rules.find((rule) => {
      return rule.test && rule.test.test(".svg");
    });
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;

    rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });
    return config;
  },

  core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
  },
  framework: "@storybook/react",
};
```

Here's my `preview.js`

```
import * as NextImage from "next/image";
import "../src/styles/globals.scss";

const OriginalNextImage = NextImage.default;

Object.defineProperty(NextImage, "default", {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => <OriginalNextImage {...props} unoptimized />,
});

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  previewTabs: {
    "storybook/docs/panel": { index: -1 },
  },
};
```

Here's my `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```